# DIV doesn't get mouse events

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseevent

I have a invisible div that on top z-index which I want to act as a clicktag button. But it does not get any mouse event I try to associate with it. Neither it does show the hand pointer specified with css.

This is the example: http://www.miguelrivero.net/test/MS-20_mini/index.html

As you can see I'm using this simple code (just focus on console.log's):

```
function bgExitHandler(e) {
    Enabler.exit("Background Exit");
    console.log("click");
}

function onMouseHandler(e) {
    console.log("click");
}

document.getElementById("bg-exit").addEventListener("click", bgExitHandler, false);
document.getElementById("bg-exit").addEventListener("onmouseover", onMouseHandler, false);
```

This is the css:

```
#bg-exit {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Any light on this, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `opacity: 0;` worth checking it out.

Comment: This smells of spam. Basically you let users think they click something whereas they actually click something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `addEventListener`, the name of the event is just `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`:

i.e.

```
document.getElementById("bg-exit").addEventListener("mouseover", onMouseHandler, false);
```

Comment: Thans for the answers. So far, I'm still stuck with this. I amended the mouseover event techfoobar suggested, but the results are the same. This should be a simple invisible button over a banner for tracking purposes. I've even followed the doubleclick model, but no luck.